# Want to change color of a shape in google docs using google API

Tags: api, doc

**Google Docs api** returns EmbeddedObjectProperties always blank.
I have placed a drawing in google doc header and footer and i want to change color of drawing using google drive api but every time unable to get drawing properties. also embeddedDrawingProperties response is blank every time in api documentation there is no explanation for embeddedDrawingProperties.

*EDIT: Her Question is related to google docs api. She wants to change color of a shape placed in header of google docs but she is unable to get the shape object and its properties.*

Comment: Please provide minimum code that can be used to reproduce the problem

Comment: I have the same problem, google docs api returns blank for EmbeddedDrawingProperties